# Do not add a comma in front of the string if value is null or empty

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If my result is null or empty I would like it not to add a comma in front of the string. How can I achieve that?

```
  Update Companies 
    set address4 = concat(address4,','+ t.Eircode) 
    From companies c
    Inner Join Temptbl1 t
    on c.comp_id = t.Comp_ID
    OR address4 = ''
```

Update :

Just to make it clear when I make this update

```
   ,V05 TTX1 
    Waterford,X01 B234
    ,B90 E902
    Co Wexford,TD2 PVE2
```

It adds a comma regardless ,if it was empty or not

What I want to get back is this  :

```
    V05 TTX1 
    Waterford,X01 B234
    B90 E902
    Co Wexford,TD2 PVE2
```

If there is no value then just add the string without the comma ,in our case `V05 TTX1` without `,` at the start of the string

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[companies](
    [comp_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [address4] [varchar](32) NOT NULL
)


INSERT INTO [dbo].[companies]
           ([comp_id]
            ,[address4])
```

Comment: Why are you storing this calculation? You can always derive it when you need it. Otherwise you're going to have to have triggers on both tables to keep it up to date. ALSO: What is `OR address4 = ''` supposed to be doing? This will actually corrupt your data by introducing many more matches than you probably intend.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are right I dont need `OR address4 = '' `  The temptbl1 is just an excel sheet I imported from Sql server , that table won't be used ,I'm just using it to accomplish my task ,I was give a list of IDs where I had to update their addresses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume t.Eircode is what concerns you. You can use a CASE statement:

```
SET address4 = concat(address4 
                     ,CASE WHEN NULLIF(address4 ,'') IS NOT NULL 
                           THEN ','+ t.Eircode 
                           ELSE '' 
                      END)
```

I also added a NULLIF function that maps '' to null so that '' and null are treated as the same.

EDIT: Given the information that address4 is NOT NULL the test can be changed to:

```
SET address4 = concat(address4 
                     ,CASE WHEN address4 <> '' 
                           THEN ',' 
                           ELSE '' 
                      END) + t.Eircode
```

It is my understanding that t.Eircode should always be concatenated, and that it is the "," that should be conditionally concatenated so I moved it out from the CASE.

Comment: Just change `NULLIF(t.Eircode,'')`  to `NULLIF(t.address4,'') `

Comment: @Lucy `t` has an `address4`? I thought that column was only in `c`? This is why `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` to set up sample data are useful, as is always prefixing all columns with the table/alias they come from.

Comment: `NULLIF(t.Eircode,'')` to `NULLIF(address4,'')` ,sorry forgot to leave out `t` ,I'll add the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` just to make it clearer to people

Comment: @Lennart ,Yes that's true  t.Eircode should always be there

Answer (score 9):

Since you are already combining `CONCAT` and `+` to concatenate strings you could just turn them around (although I agree [Lennert's solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/205343/39384) shows the intent a lot clearer).

```
Update Companies 
-- set address4 = concat(address4,','+ t.Eircode) 
set address4 = concat(address4 + ',', t.Eircode) 
From companies c
Inner Join Temptbl1 t
on c.comp_id = t.Comp_ID
OR address4 = ''
```

This works because [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) converts `NULL` into an empty string of type `varchar(1)`, but as long as [`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is on concatenating a string with NULL will yield NULL.

See this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=83b7ae9bc50479d6adbc60f34ea4da52) for an example

Comment: I believe this would allow trailing commas if `t.Eircode` is NULL; presumably, the OP only wants a comma if both `address4` and `t.Eircode` are populated.

Comment: @RDFozz That was not in the sample code and the OP's edit to Lennarts answer seems to confirm that, but you could just use + for all three strings

Comment: Combining and `CONCAT` and `+` is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I usually do this by nesting `ISNULL` and `NULLIF`:

```
UPDATE Companies
SET address4 = ISNULL(NULLIF(address4, '') + ',', '') + t.Eircode
FROM Companies c
INNER JOIN Temptbl1 t
    ON c.comp_id = t.Comp_ID
    OR address4 = ''
```